# catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include) vs. include_directories(include)

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What does the `catkin_package` call do when you specify `include` as an `INCLUDE_DIRS` and is that the same as specifying `include` inside of `include_directories`?

There is a short explanation on the template CMakeLists.txt file but it doesn't mention anything about the two above methods being the same effectively (if at all they are)? If they are not the same then what is the purpose of each individual one.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258585/catkin_package(include_dirs-include)-vs.-include_directories(include)/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The include_directories command will let the Compiler search For headers in the respective folder when compiling Files in the package the CMakeLists.txt belongs to.

The INCLUDE tag in command catkin_package will let the Compiler search for headers in the respective folder when compiling other catkin packages that depend in the package in which you added this to CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-04-04**:
So the path entered in `INCLUDE_DIRS` tag in `catkin_package()` is relative to *all* the dependent packages? That seems counterintuitive - what if different dependent packages had their header files in different relative locations?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2017-04-05**:
No, if you add include to catkin_package all dependent packages will user the include sub folder of the package in which you added it.  There own (relative) include folder still has to be added using include_directories

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-04-05**:
So if I had two packages `A` and `B` such that package `B` depends on `A`. Then in the `CMakeLists.txt` of package `A`, I should add my `INCLUDE_DIRS` so that package `B` can know where to find the files when it's compiling? That means, I should always add `INCLUDE_DIRS` whenever I have headers?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-04-06**:
Yes, assuming the headers are not just internal.